# Kafka connect JDBC sink connector - tables without Primary Key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I want to replicate 100+ tables from old MySQL server to PostgreSQL. I have setup debezium which is running fine. Now I want to setup a JDBC sink connector to PostgreSQL. Also I need to enable the DELETEs.

In this case, how can I configure my sink connector for the tables without a primary key?

It should replicate Insert, Update, and delete.

Comment: Where does it say debezium requires a primary key?

Comment: Debezium side everything is ok. Once the data in Kafka brokers, from there I'll use JDBC SINK , that SINK connector needs PK

Comment: Okay. So, do you have to use Connect?

Comment: I'm fine with anything, just wanted to sync MySQL with postgresql (insert, update, delete)

Comment: I mean, I would suggest trying out like Flink or Spark or Nifi or Streamsets if Connect doesn't work for your specific use case. Or you can fork the Connect code and fix it for everyone else in your situation, but I'm pretty sure inserts do not require a primary key

Comment: Ok great will try nifi. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you have *any* unique key on your source tables, Debezium will either use it as message key automatically in absence of a true PK column or, if not defined explicitly, you can configure the column(s) which should form the message key. I suppose it's needed on the sink side for ensuring upsert semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Debezium and Kafka Connect 2 Postgres. I have specified the key column **pk.mode=record_key** and **pk.fields=name_of_pk_column**, because it's needed by Kafka Connect, so it can delete (**enable.delete=true**) and update. Also you can set auto.evolve=true.

If you set enable.delete to true, you have to specify the PK. The column key must be the same in source and in destination table.

But this is not handy if you need to transfer more than few tables.

I did not tried it, but I think a single message transformation script might obratin the key from kafka message, transform it (maybe rename it) and us it in kafka_connect_postgres settings.

I actually have 1:1 databases on boths sides, so getting pk column name I have to only worry about.

If you desire, I can provide mine settings for Kafka connect, Kafka pg connect...

```
connector-pg.properties
name=sink-postgres
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
#tasks.max=2
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
topics=pokladna.public.books #my debezium topic with CDC from source DB
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/postgres
connection.user=postgres
connection.password=postgres
dialect.name=PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect
table.name.format=books_kafka #targe table in same db, in thus case given by url
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=false
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=upsert #insert does not work for updates
delete.enabled=true
pk.fields=id #pk column name same in target and resource db
pk.mode=record_key
```

try to use [SMT extract field](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extractfield.html#extractfield), but for me it didn't worked yet. I still have no clue how to extract the primary key from kafka message automatically. Maybe I have to write my own SMT...

Actually I'm gonna start a new SO topic about it. Haha

Comment: Ok, I will post it in separate answer.